# MonoTouch - Set Code Signing Identity to Don't Code Sign

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, code-signing

How to set the Code Signing Identity to Don't Code Sign using MonoTouch. I dont want to code sign my app. I made necessary changes in SDKSettings.plist file 
In Xcode you can select Don't code sign rather than any provisioning profile. I couldn't find any such option using MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't any way to avoid code signing your app bundles in Xamarin.